# Git bash commands are not working and don't execute

Tags: git

I used to be able to execute git commands but now I am no able to. When I execute any command, the command prompt just stops.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled git multiple times, and I have tried changing the config files. The PATH variables are also fine.

When I execute 'git pull', for example, nothing executes and I can only stop the command with Ctrl^C

Comment: Can you specify your OS, version of Git, and any other information that might help pinpoint what your configuration is like? If you're on Windows, I'm tempted to say uninstall Git and reinstall it...

Comment: I am running Windows 10 and Git Version 2.21.0. I uninstalled and reinstalled it multiple times.